# FSharp.Data.JsonProvider optional property

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm using the FSharp.Data.TypeProvider but I have an optional property that is not rendered as such.

I have this example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Friday, 24-Jul-20 16:00:00 PDT. The current time is Friday, 24-Jul-20 16:06:14 PDT.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 463,
      "fbtrace_id": "A0yQG8l8ggauD5PMbYSnEyA"
    }
  },
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Friday, 24-Jul-20 16:00:00 PDT. The current time is Friday, 24-Jul-20 16:06:14 PDT.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 463,
      "fbtrace_id": "A0yQG8l8ggauD5PMbYSnEyA"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "17841511906082530"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The field `error` is read as `Optional<Error>` meanwhile the field `data` is `Datum []`, It should be `Optional<Data>`, this error seems to have something to do with the array, if I change the value of `data` to another type, like a number, it correctly infers the type.

Maybe is some cache that's wrong? How could I reset the TypeProvider cache?

OR am I doing something else wrong?

This issue is also reported in the github project: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/1322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behavior.

In your JSON string, `data` is an array, an empty array indicates `None`, thus the field `Data` is read as array. That makes sense.

The fact that each element of that array belongs to type `Datum` also makes sense because `Datum` is the single form of `Data` (plural form). Indeed, if you rename `data` to `dogs` you will see it is read as `Dog []`.

Update: I don’t think we can tell the type provider to infer the field `data` as `Option<Datum[]>`. To check whether it is actually an empty array or not existed, we need to examine the `JsonValue` field:

```
match node.JsonValue with
| JsonValue.Record [|("data", _)|] ->
    // yep, we have field data here
| _ ->
    // nope, field data is missed
```

Comment: Thank you for the plural/singular perspective, was missing that, but what about when data doesn’t exist? Like in the case of the other two examples? It’s not an empty array in that case data is undefined.

Comment: Empty array is considered as same as non-existed. In the other two examples, `error` is not an array thus it is read as `Option<Error>`.

Comment: In rare case you need to check whether data is missed or an empty array. It that is your case, please see my update in the answer.

Comment: This is great, didn’t know I could do that, I’ve been inferring  “not error” as “with data”. But it isn’t a rare case, I mean the data might contain either the field data or error. I’ll make a test to see what happens with Data when the input is the other case to see if the parsing just puts an empty array or something. Thank you for your help 

Comment: I made the test: in the error case, if I print node it only shows the error, not the data field, but if I try to access it directly it does indeed get filled as an empty array `[| |]`. So in practice, I can assume data always has a value. Still kind of weird. But now I get how it works, thank you very much.